# How to stop RSpec anonymous class leaking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, activesupport

So I am trying to test an abstract class. According to what I have read, give an class named `Foo`, I can do the following in RSpec and it won't leak in to other tests.

```rb
let(:test) do
  Class.new(Foo) do
    # Do things here
  end
end
```

However I found that it does still leak, when I do `Foo.subclasses` in another location (depending on spec execution order).

I also tried to define the class the normal way and delete it in an after block, e.g.

```rb
let(:test) do
  class Test < Foo; end
  Test
end
...

after do
  Object.send(:remove_const, :Test)
end
```

But that also didn't seem to work. `Foo.subclasses` still seemed to contain the anonymous class.

Comment: Not sure you can undeclare an anonymous class. Those should get garbage collected *eventually* but perhaps not as soon as you'd prefer. Remember, removing a variable or constant does not automatically remove the associated object. Those may persist for other reasons, like if they're retained as a reference in the subclasses list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some investigations on how `subclasses` work, and here's what I found (though not really an answer to your question)

`subclasses` call internally `descendants` (they both come from [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/09a2979f75c51afb797dd60261a8930f84144af8/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb#L21:L52)) which calls `ObjectSpace.each_object`

If you read [it's doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/ObjectSpace.html), it says

> The ObjectSpace module contains a number of routines that interact
>   with the garbage collection facility and allow you to traverse all
>   living objects with an iterator.

It's not super clear. But AFAIU it iterates over all objects that the GC knows about.

So the reality is this: this class is not reachable unless you ask GC about it, then it can give you a reference to it. (It's kind of hacky if you ask me)

IMO you should not trust `subclasses` on any production code. It seems unpredictable. Maybe, whatever you are trying to achieve with `subclasses`, could be done in a different way? (But that's a topic for another SO question)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that. Was smashing my head against the wall. Using `subclasses` for some dynamic meta programming stuff but def have other ways to do it

Comment: What tipped me of, was this question: why a class should know about it's descendants? From the OO design this seems weird. Also all my colleagues (which are smarten than myself) are s**ing on ActiveSupport. They don't like it that much.